# Getting Search Engines To Display Desired Description

Tags: html, meta-tags

I recently tried searching my site with Google, and only one of the pages displayed the `<meta name="description" content=...>` correctly.

the meta tags are added with php via the php include function

```
<head>
    <?php 
        $description="stuff";
        $keywords="stuff";
        include ("metaTags.php"); 
    ?>
</head>
```

metaTags.php:

```
<?php 
    global $keywords, $description;
    echo '<meta name="description" content="'.$description.'" >'; 
    echo '<meta name="keywords" content="'.$keywords.'" >';
?>
```

All the pages have use the same code. I thought it may have taken a cache copy, but the new pages have the same problem. The one that doesn't has nothing special about it, except it is the most viewed.

What is displayed instead the description is the first few lines of the webpages

It displays correctly with view source.

Comment: I am not sure if this error is related: File does not exist: /var/www/robots.txt

Comment: You should show your final HTML, not the PHP code generating the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Google's algorithm decides that content text is more useful then meta description text, then it will use that in preference to a meta description.

Answer (score 0):

Search engines decide for themselves if or when to use `meta`-`description`.